# Powershell multiline pattern matching and picking those lines

Tags: regex, powershell, multiline

I am trying to pick the lines from a log file based on multi-line match. How do we achieve this with Powershell?

LogFile:

```
Date: 2020-05-06 2:30:33 PM 
   Name: ABC.txt
{text} 
{text} 
{text} 
Date: 2020-04-08 3:30:33 PM 
   Name: PQR.txt 
{text}
```

Pattern I am trying to match is:

```
Date: 
   Name:
```

I want to pull all the lines with this pattern. I tried the below line but it doesn't work.

```
get-content $log_file | select-string  -pattern "(?ms)Date:.*\nName:.*" -AllMatches
```

Output I am looking is:

```
Date: 2020-05-06 2:30:33 PM 
   Name: ABC.txt 
Date: 2020-04-08 3:30:33 PM 
    Name: PQR.txt
```

After this I want to create an array or a tabular format data(preferred) as:

```
Date|Name 
2020-05-06 2:30:33 PM|ABC.txt
2020-04-08 3:30:33 PM|PQR.txt
```

Thanks for all your support!!!!

Comment: Just as a hint for the formatting of your questions in the future: When you post code, error messages, sample data or console output - format it as code, please. ;-)

Comment: Thanks! just my first time here, so was not sure of formatting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
Get-Content $log_file -Raw |
    Select-String -Pattern '(?m)^Date:.*\r?\n\s*Name:.*' -AllMatches |
        Foreach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```

You should use the `-Raw` switch on `Get-Content` to pass in the file contents as a single string. Otherwise it is an array of strings. Using single-line modifier `(?s)`, makes `.` match newline characters. Since you only want to traverse two contiguous lines, I'd opt for just matching `\r` and `\n` explicitly without single-line modifier. Then you can use `.*` without fear of it matching beyond the current line.

Since `Select-String` returns the entire string that produced a match, you will need to return the `MatchInfo` object's property `Matches` and its property `Value` to display only the matched text.

Comment: If `$log_file` is large, using `-Raw` will require memory. http://www.happysysadm.com/2014/10/reading-large-text-files-with-powershell.html

Comment: You haven’t accepted this answer, then ask another question in the comments. I recommend the opposite of those

Comment: was trying to figure out that, just did it, thank you all!